# when do not use open source code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, open-source

Are there some cases where it may not be a good idea to use the code of an open source project even though your company might allow you to do so?

Some cases that I think might be valid are:

1. The code may be implemented in a different languages.
2. It is not portable
3. It may need some other close-source libraries

What might be some other reasons?

Comment: This kind of open-ended questions (pun not intended) may find a better audience at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If your account is even allowed to post questions any more, please stop asking *this kind* of question. You will almost certainly be banned for it very shortly. Read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [how to ask questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) before that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some open-source licenses may require you to expose your source code, e.g GPL.

http://encodable.com/tech/blog/2006/02/25/Why_the_GPL_is_Incompatible_with_Commercial_Software

Answer (score 0):

When security is involved and you do not have access to the actual code so you never (truly) know what you are using.

Beta code may not be appropriate in a production system.

if the library has a web page and there hasn't been any activity on it for a long long time.  Either the code is perfect or no one is looking at the code anymore and no bug fixes are being applied.